# Android EditText Left Icon color change on Focus?

Tags: android

As seen in Google Material design:
[image: Google Material Design Example]
I have implemented same functionality but I did that manually.

Here is my xml:

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:text="@string/email_icon"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_25" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.teafloor.utils.EditTextCustom
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passWordIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:textSize="@dimen/sp_25"
                android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
                android:text="@string/password_icon" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/darkGrey"
                app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/visibility_selector"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                <com.teafloor.utils.EditTextCustom
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

And this is my manual logic:

```
  emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            emailIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            if (!passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                passwordIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }else {
                passwordIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGrey));
            }
        }
    });

passwordEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            passwordIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            if (!emailEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                emailIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }else {
                emailIcon.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGrey));
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I change the color of each edittext manually inside the onFocusChangeListener, the problem in this is if I have more edittexts I'll have to check the empty condition for each edittext and then change its color.

I have to keep the icons outside the edittext, so I can't use drawableLeft or drawableStart.

What I have implemented works fine for me but I was looking for a more simpler way, just like the [google's password toggle feature](http://codevscolor.com/2016/08/android-material-design-tutorial-10-password-visibility-toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
emailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
passwordEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and the implement OnFocusChangeListener with override method

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    View child = parent.getChildAt(0);
    if (b) {
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) child).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        }
    }else{
        EditText editText = (EditText) view;
        if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) child).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGrey));
            }
        }else{
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) child).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just converted my code to a simpler format by overriding the onFocusChange Listener. I am looking for a simpler implementation not simplified code.

Comment: Now you don't have to write code for every edittext. Thats what you wanted right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add theme for EditText

```html
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary</item>
</style>

and use in your Edittext
<EditText
   .......................
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">

</EditText>
```